# SockException: Profile page will not load

Tags: bug, user-profile

I made a [sock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/108901/lazers-2-0), but when I tried to access it's profile page to edit in the fact it is a sock, it threw an error.

Comment: The problem is spreading, I just tried to access my meta profile (for fredley) and got the same(?) error. Main profile for fredley still accessible.

Comment: All meta sites except meta.stackexchange using the new profile seem to have the same problem.

Comment: @Unionhawk I hope I didn't cause this...

Comment: I can't access my own profile anymore either, but can access others, including fredleys and his sock's.

Comment: seems to be fixed now

Comment: @fredley, ignore my ignorance, but what is a sock? (other than the thing you put on your foot)

Comment: @AngusAtkinson By sock, he means something similar to a [sockpuppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_%28Internet%29). Essentially, it is a fake user controlled by fredley. Unlike a normal sockpuppet, this one is not particularly deceptive.

Comment: @ken.ganong But how could that be useful? Wouldn't it just get him banned for alt accounts? Or is it for moderation purposes?

Comment: @AngusAtkinson His intention was to use it for testing what things look like for a non-moderator user. fredley mentioned his intention on doing so as a comment on this [previous meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10450/2k-flags-51-useful).

Comment: @ken.ganong Ahh. Thankyou. That has clarified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Oded at [Meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254031/265769)

> An attempt at fixing an issue with reputation graphs has not taken into account that meta sites don't have reputation.

It has been fixed now.